# Is geoext 3 working with open layers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3, geoext3

Is geoext 3 working with open layers 3?

Can I use open layers 3 with geoext version 3?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes GeoExt 3 works with OpenLayers version 3. But it's not released yet, it's work in progress. But you're free to try it out.

Comment: I am having errors while using it. Can you solve this? stackoverflow.com/questions/32456801/invalid-instanceof-operand-ol-layer-base-in-geoext3